# Create new view through code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Is it possible to add a new view from code that can be executed on a button click? In stack overflow, a new view is generated when we post a question. Is is possible to do this in ASP.NET MVC5?

Comment: is there something is missing .. ? the some code I  guess

Comment: @shu I didn't get what you are saying. please elaborate a little more

Comment: Why people have down voted? I don't think it has any problem. Pls tell if it has any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create a new view from code. But why do you need it. I guess to provide a different URL to each table entry so that it indexes better.  For that you can change the URL of your details view.